# Saving multiple files using template and for loop Python

Tags: python

Inside my input dir I have three reports FinalReport_Nm, FinalReport_S01, FinalReport_S02 etc.  I will be adding about 50 more reports to this so the naming will continue on with S03, S04, T01, T02 etc. What I want this script to do is loop through the folder of reports, take FinalReport_NM, and paste it into my template, and then save this as SecondaryReport_1a_NM, and then loop back through and copy FinalReport_S01, paste it to the template, and save as SecondaryReport_1a_S01 etc.

I though by creating schedules NM S01 S02 as seen below in the script and trying to concatenate at the bottom where it says output_file would work but this is a huge fail.  How can I get this script to work where it will rename the files as it loops through them.

```
import openpyxl as xl; 
import os
 
input_dir = 'C:\\Python\\Reports'
output_dir = 'C:\\Reports\\output'
template = 'C:\\Python\\Report_Template.xlsx'
NewFileName = 'SecondaryReport_1a_'

schedule_index = 0
schedules=['Nm', 'S01', 'S02']
  
files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith('.xlsx')]
  
for file in files:
    input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file) 
    wb=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
    ws=wb.worksheets[1]
      
    # Open template
    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(template) 
    ws2 = wb2.worksheets[2] 
     
    # calculate total number of rows and  
    # columns in source excel file 
    mr = ws.max_row 
    mc = ws.max_column 
     
    # copying the cell values from source  
    # excel file to destination excel file 
    for i in range (1, mr + 1): 
        for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
             
    # reading cell value from source excel file 
            c = ws.cell(row = i, column = j) 
    # Cells for source data to pasted inside Template
            ws2.cell(row = i+12, column = j+1).value = c.value 
     
    # saving the destination excel file 
    output_file = (output_dir, f"{summaryFile}_{schedules[schedule_index]}")
    schedule_index += 1
    wb2.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Tell us how it fails...does it print an error message or raise an exception?  Does it save any files? etc.

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you have several xlsx files that have file names of the format "FinalReport_(suffix).xlsx", where suffix can be "Nm", "S01", "S01", "T01", etc.  For each one, you want to create a new file with a name like "SecondaryReport_1a_(suffix).xlsx", where the suffix is the same.

For this simple case, the suffix can be extracted using string slicing:

```
prefix_length = len("FinalReport_")
suffix = file[:prefix_length]
```

The output filename can be created like so:

```
output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"SecondaryReport_1a_{suffix}.xlsx")
```